# a man destroyed

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

Can one say

a. In front of you, you see a man destroyed.

b. In front of you, you see men destroyed.

if the intended meaning is

c. In front of you, you see a man/men who has/have **been destroyed**.... **a destroyed man/destroyed men**.

?

The sentences could mean

d. If front of you, you see a man/men **get destroyed**.

But could they be used if the 'destruction' is over and done with?

My feeling is that they could be used in poetry with that meaning.

Many thanks.

Comment: I have nothing to add to JeezLouise's answer, but wanted to mention that I've seen this form used in various places, often as a bit of an artistic flourish.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

> In front of you, you see a man destroyed.

This can mean:

> In front of you, you see a man who has been destroyed.

indicating that the destruction has taken place in the past.

Actually, it *only* means that the destruction has already taken place. If the destruction is currently taking place, one would say a phrase more like the following:

> In front of you, you see a man being destroyed.
>
> In front of you, you see the destruction of a man.

This is because in the sentence "In front of you, you see a man destroyed", *destroyed* is an adjective, thus meaning that whatever has caused the object (man) to become destroyed has already taken place; similarly, if you say that you are seeing "a man asleep", it means that the man has already fallen asleep.